# база данных sql mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Ка задать значение `по умолчанию` для параметра в хранимой процедуре

Answer (score 2):

**Опциональные параметры** не поддерживаются в MySQL на уровне определения заголовка хранимой процедуры.

Однако, вы можете воспользоваться следующей инструкцией в начале тела хранимой процедуры для определения значения по умолчанию:

```
SET myParameter = IFNULL(myParameter, 0);
```

IFNULL является одной из функций потока управления MySQL, которая принимает два аргумента и возвращает первый, если он не равен NULL. Иначе она возвращает второй аргумент.